# Algorithm to suggest correction for wrong input?

Tags: algorithm

I have a table of actors with columns containing biographical information. Each row will be a different actor. I will store all actors in a list.

When my program prompt for an actor's name, it will print out their biographical info.

However, I wonder is there any algorithm that will suggest the correct input when I type the input wrong?

For example, when I type: Jenniger Lopez, the program will suggest Jennifer Lopez.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you may look for the letters matched and if the majority of letters match (you could also play with the order of the letters), you may suggest the similar data. Aside from that, I think this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: The classical way is to use an algorithm called Edit Distance https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/edit-distance-dp-5/

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understood you have a list of actors and in case the user mistypes you want to give him the best match from your list.

In that case the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) is a classic approach.

This basically calculates a distance between two words/strings. In your case, if you do not find an exact match, find the match with the smallest Levenshtein distance